# Reload same URL in webview when refresh

Tags: android, webview, reload, pull-to-refresh

I created a little android app to view a responsive website. I have implemented a pull refresh and it works, however when pulling on refresh it redirect to the home page I put in the LoadUrl. How to refresh by reloading the same url the user is visiting ?

My java code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
    swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            LoadWeb();
        }
    });
    LoadWeb();
}
public void LoadWeb(){

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new Client());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new ChromeClient());

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    }
    else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=15 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
    swipe.setRefreshing(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com"); 
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
        }

        public  void  onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
            //Hide the SwipeReefreshLayout
            swipe.setRefreshing(false);
        }

    });
}
```

Main Activity:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.www.appexample.MainActivity">
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to save the redirect url each time user navigates .

```
 private String currentUrl="http://www.example.com";


    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            currentUrl=url;
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    });
```

make your `LoadWeb` method parameterized to accept a String.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                LoadWeb(currentUrl);
            }
        });
        LoadWeb("http://www.example.com");
    }
```

Comment: Thank u. I put the above code and parameterized LoadWeb but still no succes. Maybe I'm missing something ? `public void LoadWeb(String url)`

Comment: Change this line 'webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");' pass the argument as url .

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the content of your OnRefresh method to
webView.reload();

Answer (score 0):

I had implemented reloading functionality in android WebView using a simple stack . In general shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method will give you the URL that pressed while using  the webview app .  You can push the URL while clicking in any link , as

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        try{
            urlStack.push(url);
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Then while reloading the webview peek the top URL from the stack and load in the webview as,

```
webview.loadUrl(urlStack.peek());
```

That can be disturbing  after  back pressing , and then you reloaded the WebView then the WebView reloaded to the same URL . but it suppose to reloading the current page . so you have to do it like that . When you back press , an URL have to remove from the stack as

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                    try{
                        urlStack.pop();
                    }catch (Exception e){

                    }
                    webView.goBack();
                } else {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                            .setTitle("Closing app")
                            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close this app?")
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    finish();
                                }

                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                            .show();
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

The code will remove the top URL from the stack , and after going back the page's URL will be in the top of the stack , so you will reload the URL that belongs to the page .

If you need more explanation or code you can go to those links .

https://github.com/mahmud-jerry/Android-Webview-Reloading-With-Stack

Answer (score -1):

You can set `webView.Source`

```java
webView.Source = new Uri(@"https://www.your_url.com");
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. Thanks